# Methods for improving efficiency when drawing paths in java.awt

Tags: java, scala, performance, awt, graphics2d

I am using the java.awt.Canvas class for drawing in my application and it simply does not seem to be fast enough. After filling my screen with some hand drawn math I get to a point where I am running at 70 fps and just rendering takes up about 90% of the time each frame. I wonder what I can do to spend less time drawing.

I have so far done the following to try and decrease the time needed to draw.

1. I only draw what is visible on the screen(to compute what is visible does not take a significant amount of time). I have also confirmed it works as when I pan away from the lines my frame rate spikes to upwards of 4000 fps.
2. I have implemented an algorithm to simplify paths(only computed once when I create a path).
   Interactive showcase of what it does: http://paperjs.org/examples/path-simplification/

This is the code which does the drawing.

```scala
def render(drawAbsolute: Graphics2D => Unit, drawFromCamera: Graphics2D => Unit, camera: Camera): Unit = 
        import java.awt.Color
        var bs = getBufferStrategy
        if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3)
        bs = getBufferStrategy
        }
        val g2d = bs.getDrawGraphics().asInstanceOf[Graphics2D]
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
        )
        g2d.setColor(backgroundColor)
        g2d.fillRect(Vector2.zero, canvasSize)
        drawAbsolute(g2d) // this is fast because I am not drawing anything here atm :)
        g2d.setTransform(camera.transform)
        drawFromCamera(g2d)  // This line takes up about 90% of the frame time. (Only draws a couple of hundred lines).
        bs.show()
        g2d.dispose()
```

Drawing code for my paths

```scala
override val shape: Shape = path2D
override def draw(g2d: Graphics2D): Unit =
  g2d.draw(shape)
```

Also worth noting that not redrawing areas might be hard since the user is able to rotate and pan around. I guess that I could call a redraw function or something everytime the camera transform changes, I do feel however that it opens up a scary can of worms not redrawing everything everyframe and I will constantly have to think about.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Update your post to clarify the specific problem you need to resolve.